# Regular expression for a palindrome

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for a particular kind of palindrome. The rules are

1. The length is 5;
2. In the first two characters, one should be a capitalized letter, and the other should be a digit;
3. The third character is a letter in lower case .

The main difficulty for me is the undetermined positions of the group references.
If I write `'(((([A-Z])([0-9]))|(([0-9])([A-Z])))[a-z]\5\4)'`, only `K2i2K` but not `2KiK2` will be matched. To match `2KiK2`, I have to write `'(((([A-Z])([0-9]))|(([0-9])([A-Z])))[a-z]\8\7)'`.

So how should I write the regular expression? Thank you.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Why would you match `2KiK2`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Because it clearly respects his requirements!

Comment: Yeah, I misread the question. I assumed the _first_ character is supposed to be alphabet.

Answer (score 4):

```
\b(?=.{5})(?=(?:[A-Z]\d|\d[A-Z]))(.)(.)[a-z]\2\1\b
```

This asserts (with positive look-aheads) that there are 5 characters and also that the first two are either a Capital-Digit or a Digit-Capital pair.

Once we are sure of that, the rest is trivial. We capture the first two characters, check for a lowercase letter and then match the first two captures in reversed order.

I also surrounded the regex with word boundaries (`\b`) to make sure it doesn't match in the middle of a word.

See it on [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xH7uB6/2) with a detailed explanation.

Comment: Ah, bummed I didn't do this.

Comment: Not clear about the lookahead part. I am using Python and the documentation says "For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.". It sounds to me that the interested part should go before the lookahead assertion. But why is `(.)(.)` after the assertion?

Comment: The look-ahead asserts something about the characters that follow but it does not consume/match them. Once we have asserted that the characters are indeed what we're looking for we can simply capture anything (with the `(.)(.)` construct) because we already know that they are good.

Answer (score 2):

I would say make your life easy and just use a simple alternation for the 2 scenarios:

```
([A-Z])([0-9])[a-z]\2\1|([0-9])([A-Z])[a-z]\4\3
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/sI0zP9/1)

---

This will look for `A-Z`, `0-9`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `A-Z` OR `0-9`, `A-Z`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`.  While you may think it takes a performance hit, it really shouldn't.  It will either match `A-Z` and try to go the first route (if it fails at any point, it will try to match `0-9` and fail with one extra step) OR fail at `A-Z` and try to match starting at `0-9`.  Either way, it only really has potentially one extra step on success/failure.